# How do I set "no value" on the server to be compatible with Backbone?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, backbone.js

What I mean by this is I want to use the defaults object literal of Models, which calls this code from underscore:

**Temp Code**

```
var Feed = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        picture: '', // I need this set when picture is 0
        time: '',
        tweet: ''
        // h_file, view_picture
    }
});
```

**From Underscore**

```
_.defaults = function(obj) {
    each(slice.call(arguments, 1), function(source) {
      if (source) {
        for (var prop in source) {
          if (obj[prop] === void 0) obj[prop] = source[prop];
        }
      }
    });
    return obj;
  };
```

It will only set a default if a value is set to `undefined`.  However JSON does not support sending `undefined`, nor do I see this as default value in the mysql table I use.

Obviously, I can use an intermediary value, which is what I'm currently doing.  I just store the number 0 as a default for no value and send this via JSON, and then just do a basic if/else.

But this is in-efficient and I would imagine there is a better 1 to 1 correlation I could use.

Comment: You should use a function that returns an Object as your `default` eg. `defaults: function () { /* do your magic */ return {name: null, picture: null} }`  oh, you should use `null` instead of `undefined` for empty fields

Comment: the point was that I  need `undefined` and JSON does not support `undefined`.  Although `null` is good b.c. I can use it as a default at the server and JSON will support it, it will not work b.c. `_.defaults` will not recognize it.

Comment: your `_.defaults` doesn't recognize null because you are comparing `obj[prop]` with `void 0` which returns `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the built in parse method otherwise I do not see a way around it. It's a difficult predicament, because what would you consider a value that would result in your default value being set? I came up with a quick solution that will filter out ALL values that are considered falsy. You can build on the below.

```
parse: function(data) {
    // This should return values that are truthy
    // So for eg if a property has a value of 0 or null it will not be returned,
    // thus leaving in your default values
    return _.filter(data, function(obj) { return obj; });
}
```

I found a request for it here as well https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/157

Comment: I think setting to a `null` at the server so that JSON will send it, and then parsing it at the client so that all `null` values are converted to `undefined` is a good solution.

Comment: Ya then in your parse method you could amend the above to `return obj !== null;`

Comment: yep, a nice quick function will fix this, no need to make a mountain out of an ant hill.